# Slumdog millionaire (10)

Tags: knowledge, sports

My Indian friend Jamal recently participated in the well-known TV quiz
show ***[Who wants to be a millionaire?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire)***. You might have heard or read about Jamal's spectacular success; the media reported on it extensively.

Here is what Jamal told us about the 32.000 Euro question:

> Oh no, the 32.000 Euro question was a sports question! The second safe haven suddenly seemed far away, perhaps out of reach!  Although I enjoy exercising myself, I have not paid much attention to professional sports.  Unfortunately, this question was not about the Raiders or the Lakers.
>
> At first sight, all four answers seemed perfectly acceptable. I thought to
>   vaguely remember that D is particularly strong in that sport, and also has
>   many good teams playing in the national competition. But I also thought to
>   vaguely remember that they had become world champion the time **before**,
>   as at that time the final had been particularly violent.  Not that I had
>   watched this final, but it just was all over the media and there was no way
>   of not hearing about it.  Aha, and then I suddenly remembered that C had also
>   been involved in these ruthless acts of kung fu violence.  Hence C and D had
>   been the finalists **the time before**, and this should have eliminated them,
>   unless of course one of them managed to make it to the final again next time.
>   Darn. Darn. Darn.
>
> I read the question once again, and decided to go with A or B. I cautiously
>   said: "Perhaps it is answer A", and saw a lickety-split happy flash in Prem's
>   eyes.  Prem wanted me to lose.  So A had to be wrong.  Yes, yes, yes, yes, yes! I went for answer B.  (After the show and only much later I found out, that A in fact had been B's opponent in the deciding match of that world championship.)
>
> But the only thing that really mattered was that I had picked the right answer! Prem swallowed hard, and his eyes popped out a little bit. "Answer B is corrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrect, my frrrrrrrrrrrrrrrriend!" This was good enough to get me to the 64.000 Euro question.

***What was the 32.000 Euro question?

What were the four possible answers A, B, C, D?***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems too easy to be the 32.000 Euro question.

---

The question was:

> Who won the 2014 FIFA World Cup?

The answer choices were:

> **A)** Argentina
>  **B)** Germany
>  **C)** Netherlands
>  **D)** Spain

Justification:

> **Spain** won the 2010 FIFA World Cup, with a 1-0 victory over **The Netherlands**. There was some pretty raucous violence during the game, including a couple of "kung-fu kick" fouls. Spain also has quite a few good football teams (in fact, football is the national sport of Spain). The 2014 World Cup championship was Germany versus Argentina, in which Germany was victorious.

Comment: I can't find fault with this, nice work.

Answer (score 5):

My answer is very similar to Bailey M's but I had a different question in my head that also fits these circumstances.

**Question:**

> Who was the champion of the 2010 FIFA World Cup?

**Choices:**

> A. Netherlands
>  B. Spain
>  C. France
>  D. Italy

**Rationale:**

> - Italy (D) is particularly strong in soccer/football/calcio/futbol behind club sides like Juventus, Inter Milan, AC Milan, and Roma.
>  - They were in the 2006 FIFA World Cup Final against France (C) where Zinedine Zidane famously head-butted (also a move in kung-fu) Marco Materazzi in the chest.
>  - In the 2010 final, Spain defeated the Netherlands to become champion.

**Note:**

> The OP may very well be looking for Bailey M's answer, because if I recall correctly, Nigel de Jong's kick out into Xabi Alonso was dubbed a kung-fu kick by the media. Given how general the puzzle is, my answer also fits very well. Also, for a 32k question, going back 4 more years into the past makes more sense.

Comment: Yours was my first instinct, but the kick I think was more kung fu than the headbutt. Soccer is cool!